# is it possible to change the value of a instance variable from the different class thread After acquiring a lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

is it possible to change the value of a instance variable from the different class thread After acquiring a lock.

I have a class ThreadTest, it has String test instance variable.
In Run method i have taken a lock on String test instance variable.

if JVM has already taken  a lock on instance variable then why im able to change the value it from main thread.

### ThreadTest.class

package com;

public class ThreadTest implements Runnable{

```
String test;
int i=100;

public ThreadTest(String test) {
    super();
    this.test = test;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


//  Thread.currentThread().dumpStack();
    while(i>0)
    {   
        synchronized(test){


        System.out.println("Thrad Test Run---  "+test+" - "+i+"- -- "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        i--;
    }
}
```

}

### Test.class

package com;

public class Test {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ThreadTest testThread=new ThreadTest("1");
    Thread thread=new Thread(testThread);
    thread.setName("First Thread");
    Thread thread1=new Thread(testThread);
    thread1.setName("Second Thread");

    thread.start();
    thread1.start();
    int i=100;  
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(true)
    {
        //here im accessing the 'test' that is instance variable of ThreadTest.
        // and First Thread alredy acquired a lock on 'test'.
        //so according to the JAVA threading testThread.test=10 is not valid.
        //how multiple threads are able to change the value of testThread.test
        testThread.test="10";
        //System.out.println("main thread...");
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be confusion about what the synchronized statement does.

1. **synchronized** does not lock an instance variable, it 'locks' an object. (Actually, 'lock' isn't the word used here.  It acquires the object's 'monitor'.)  When a synchronized statement is used (as above), the provided expression is evaluated to determine which object's monitor to acquire.  For example, here are valid, though probably nonsensical, synchronized statements:

   ```
   synchronized ("1") {
      // ... 
   }

   synchronized (new Object()) {
      // ...
   }
   ```

   The first acquires the monitor on the String object representing the     string literal "1".  The second acquires the monitor on a brand new object (which is *never* useful for managing concurrency).
2. **synchronized** is for marking a critical section in a program.  A critical section is a block of code that must not be executed concurrently. [See Critical Section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)

   In regards to the code above, **synchronized** does not prevent reads or writes of instance (or class) variables.

The following might be helpful: [Synchronization from the Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to ... after acquiring a lock.

If thread A acquires a lock, that does not limit the ability of thread A to do anything in any way whatsoever.

If thread A acquires a lock, it limits the ability of thread B to do exactly one thing:  It prevents thread B from acquiring the same lock until thread A has released it.  It does not prevent thread B from doing anything else.  In particular, it does not prevent thread B from accessing or modifying the object that is "locked".

> Is it possible to change the value of a instance variable...

Yes, if the variable is not `final`.

> ...from the different class

Whether or not a method in class A can refer directly to a variable declared in class B depends on the *access level* (`private`, `protected`, `public`, or *default*) that is specified in the variable's declaration.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

The use of `synchronized` blocks and the use of threads do not change the meaning of access levels in any way.

Of course, a method in class A may also be able to indirectly affect even a `private` variable in class B by calling some method of class B.

> ...from the different ... thread

If a method in class A can directly or indirectly affect a variable declared in class B, then it does not matter what thread is executing the method.  All threads see the same heap.